# How to Join two tables with SUM and GROUP BY in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, join, query, group-by, sum

I have 2 tables

1. product

| id | designation |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | coca |
| 2 | Pepsi |
| 3 | Fanta |
| 4 | Seven |
| 5 | Eight |

2)sub_product

| product_id | name | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sm | 10 |
| 1 | lg | 10 |
| 1 | xl | 20 |
| 2 | 1L | 10 |
| 2 | 2L | 20 |
| 2 | 5L | 20 |
| 3 | Ty | 10 |
| 3 | Sa | 20 |
| 4 | ha | 20 |
| 4 | kd | 30 |

what I wanna have is this:
the designation from the product table and total quantity which represent the SUM of the quantity that have the same product_id

| designation | total quantity |
| --- | --- |
| Coca | 40 |
| Pepsi | 50 |
| Fanta | 30 |
| Seven | 50 |

Notes : I use SQL server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be accomplished simply with a [`JOIN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver15) and [`GROUP_BY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause like so:

```
SELECT 
    p.designation, 
    SUM(ISNULL(sp.quantity, 0)) AS [total quantity]
FROM product AS p
LEFT JOIN sub_product AS sp
    ON p.id = sp.product_id
GROUP BY p.id, p.designation
```

Note the use of a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (aka a `LEFT JOIN`) to ensure that even `products` without any `sub_products` are still returned (with a `total quantity` of 0). If it's guaranteed there'll always be at least 1 `sub_product` for every `product` then you can use an `INNER JOIN` instead.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you group by `designation`?

Comment: @mustaccio Good point, I was having a brain fart when I originally wrote that, so you're right that *generally* you could group by the *value* field here. The one case where not grouping by it makes sense though is if it's not unique, i.e. there are two different `product`s with the same `designation` but different `id`s (assuming the `id` field is unique here - either by primary key or some other constraint). Then the query I provided will ensure you get the accurate totals back with a separate row for each instance of the *duplicate* `designation`.

Comment: @mustaccio Also clearly my brain fart continues, as to solve the problem I mentioned, I can just keep `id` in the grouping key as well. Updated my answer lol. Thanks.

Comment: Grouping by P.ID is superfluous as it it isn't in the select list.

Comment: ISNULL(Qty,0) is assuming there is no matching product - which would not resolve into Designation, and is also superfluous.

Comment: LEFT JOIN is sub-optimal due to the fact that products without Qty are irrelevant. In fact, the query optimiser will do it for you as you have no conditions on any field in the left joined table.

Comment: @Alocyte 1. I stated why `p.id` is needed in an earlier comment: "*[if] there are two different `products` with the same `designation` but different `id`s*" - so it's not superfluous. 2. The `ISNULL()` check is against `sub_product` which is on the outer-side of the join, and is needed if you one doesn't want `NULL`s. 3. "*products without Qty are irrelevant*" - That's up to OP, and future readers with similar problems, not you lol. To many, it would be relevant. In conclusion, what are you doing wasting your time commenting on a year old answer?

Comment: @J.D. :) I am pissed my answer was downvoted... so commenting to elaborate how it is perfect.  There shouldn't be a duplicate on product designations  - that bad data. NULL will not show up - you are grouping. Only products with Qty are summed, 0 are not relevant... Have a great day :)

Comment: @Alocyte "*There shouldn't be a duplicate on product designations - that bad data.*" - And no one should have to work, or get sick, but the world isn't perfect unfortunately. You never know what kind of data there will be, so it's better to code defensively. As far as your downvote, unfortunately I wouldn't know why whoever downvoted you did, but perhaps it's because of lack of explanation with your answer. Best of luck!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Designation, SUM(Qty)
FROM Product P
JOIN sub_product Q
ON Q.Product_ID = P.id
GROUP BY Designation
ORDER BY Designation
```

? downvoted? LOL

```
DECLARE @Product TABLE (ID INT, Designation VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @Sub_Product TABLE ( product_id INT, name varchar(10), Quantity INT)
INSERT INTO @Product (ID, Designation) VALUES
(1,'coca'),
(2,'Pepsi'),
(3,'Fanta'),
(4,'Seven'),
(5,'Eight')

INSERT INTO @Sub_Product (product_id, name, Quantity) VALUES
(1,'sm',10),
(1,'lg',10),
(1,'xl',20),
(2,'1L',10),
(2,'2L',20),
(2,'5L',20),
(3,'Ty',10),
(3,'Sa',20),
(4,'ha',20),
(4,'kd',30)

SELECT Designation, SUM(Quantity) [Total Quantity]
FROM @Product P
JOIN @sub_product Q
ON Q.Product_ID = P.id
GROUP BY Designation
ORDER BY Designation
```

RESULT:

```
Designation Total Quantity
coca    40
Fanta   30
Pepsi   50
Seven   50
```